# Adjust image on UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview, uibutton

I have custom button, with an image that I'd like to shift down within the button. I don't want to mess with the clickable portion of the button, but just want the image moved. I've tried adjusting button.imageview.frame, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Here's my code:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 25.0);
UIImage *buttonOnImage = [@"tabbar_icon_0"];

[button setImage:buttonOnImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setImage:buttonOnImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIButton` has `imageEdgeInsets` property, which can be used to shift image inside the button.

In most cases it helps a lot. You can access it from IB (in `Edge` drop down choose `Image` and then change `Inset` fields), so you can try different values and see if it works for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not adjust the image's size by padding it out with transparency in Photoshop?

Comment: I probably could, but I'd like more fine control and would rather adjust it programatically. Why, is it not possible?

Comment: I guess that it's possible, I'm not @ a mac right now so I can't test.